# Python : Bucketing/clustering based on status of active/Inactive

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

There are n number of rooms which contains m number of bulbs, i want to make pair of bulbs which were switched **ON** after another.
Only add bulb to a bucket if it is switched **ON**

```
room    bulb    switch  datetime
r1      b1      off     03-02-2020 12:15
r2      b1      on      03-02-2020 12:20
r1      b2      on      03-02-2020 12:22
r3      b2      on      03-02-2020 12:26
r1      b1      on      03-02-2020 12:42
r2      b3      on      03-02-2020 12:55
r4      b5      off     03-02-2020 12:15
r1      b2      off     03-02-2020 13:15
r3      b4      on      03-02-2020 13:19
r1      b1      on      03-02-2020 13:27
r2      b4      on      03-02-2020 13:45
r4      b5      on      03-02-2020 12:22
r4      b3      on      03-02-2020 12:35
r3      b2      off     04-02-2020 12:15
r4      b3      off     04-02-2020 12:22
r4      b1      on      05-02-2020 16:15
r4      b4      on      05-02-2020 16:22
r4      b3      on      05-02-2020 16:35
r4      b1      off     05-02-2020 16:22
r2      b3      off     04-02-2020 12:22
r2      b1      on      05-02-2020 16:15
r2      b4      on      05-02-2020 16:22
r2      b3      on      05-02-2020 16:35
r2      b1      off     05-02-2020 16:42


For Example :
r1->b2,b1
r3->b5,b3
r2->(b1,b3,b4) ,(b1,b4,b3)
r4->(b5,b3),(b1,b4,b3)
```

Comment: Hello @Sahil, what is your code so far? add it in your question.

Comment: your example is strange. if i sort the values the logic cannot be as your described